# How to detect whether last item in ALAssetLibrary is photo or video?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, alassetslibrary

I'm developing a camera app. In that I need to display the last image from camera roll in the bottom. I'm able to do this using ALAssetsLibrary. And if the last item in camera roll is a video, I need to display the first thumbnail image from that video. But how to detect the last item in camera roll is whether photo or video so that i can be able to display whether last image or first image of the video from camera roll?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @dev- why dont you store everytime you pick a image or video in nsuserdefault

Comment: How to detect that is photo or video even it is stored in NSUserDefaults? There are separate methods to display last image and to display first image of video. If i know the last one is photo or video i can call the methods accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

the delegate method can let you know what is the file a image or a video

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {
            NSString *type = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
            //NSLog(@"type=%@",type);
            if ([type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeVideo] || 
                [type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
            {// movie != video
                NSURL *urlvideo = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
            }
            else{
                 // image
                }
     }
```

Comment: But i don't want to detect it after picking from library using UIImagePickerController. I want to detect it to show at the bottom of camera screen automatically by using ALAssetsLibrary.

Comment: @Dev- after picking you can save it that the last object was video or image.

Comment: Please observe the functionality of camera in iPhone. If we take photo or video it will be displayed automatically in bottom. I want to do the same.

Comment: @Dev- your question was how to detect the last picked image or video, my answer can be used with some modification. and then you can do what you want